# Make a relative url go one step back

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a url: http://test.com/test1/test2/
Is there a way to make a relative url from test2 to test1? Like just one step back?
Without Javascript.
The /test1/ part may change, that's why I need to go from /test/2 just one step back to /test1/ (or to a changed url)

Comment: Is this in a template? What is actually displayed at test1 and test 2 respectively? Need a bit more info here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link with `../`. Indeed, if you visit `/test1/test2/` and the URL contains `../`, it will move one directory up, so `/test1/`.

This is specified in [RFC-3986 of the W3 organization <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986), in the [*Merge paths* section <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.3), and as [section 3.3 on *Paths* <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) describes:

> The **path segments `"."` and `".."`**, also known as dot-segments, are
> defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference ([Section 4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.2)) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical tree of names.  This is similar to their role within some operating systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory and **parent directory, respectively**.

You thus can make a link to go to the "parent directory" that looks like:

```
<a href="../">parent<a>
```